# ORA-00338: log # of thread # is more recent than control file

Tags: oracle, transaction-log

We are facing the following error on our production database:

> ORA-00338: log # of thread # is more recent than control file

The database crashed and there was no recovery action. What could I do to resolve the problem?

Comment: Tried superuser or Dba forum?

Comment: Are there any other errors given? This error usually accompanies some others which are the actual source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you are opening using the wrong control file[s]. This is easily caused when using for example a parameter file in ASM - the correct one - and one in the default location $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/ that still has the old references in place after a migration to ASM. In that case search in ASM to the current control files.

In such a setup, normally the parameter is found by using `srvctl config database -d YOUR_DB`

During every opening attempt the log# is increased .... so after many attempts, the error can go away and the problem can still exist ....

Answer (score -1):

Error Cause:

The control file change sequence number in the log file is greater than the number in the control file. This implies that the wrong control file is being used. Note that repeatedly causing this error can make it stop happening without correcting the real problem. Every attempt to open the database will advance the control file change sequence number until it is great enough.

```
ACTION:
Use the current control file or do backup control file recovery to make the control file current. Be sure to follow all restrictions on doing a backup control file recovery.
```

Comment: whats wrong here to down vote??